# How to draw a string on two not adjacent areas

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gdi+, gdi

I can not figure out if there is there any way in GDI32 to draw a string on two not adjacent areas (let's say Rectangles) on a form?.

The text should automatically split if the edge of the first rectangle is reached as shown in the example picture.
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: draw it off-screen to a sufficiently wide rectangle, then copy the parts of that to your final layout (assuming you *really* meant to split the text in the middle of a character, which is quite unusual, consider proper word wrapping instead). for useful answers, please restrict to either c# or vb, and to either GDI or GDI+, and include the code you've got so far.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was thinking. I'm wondering if there is a 'native' methods, like adding multiple non adjacent rectangle on a region and then drawing some text on it

Comment: If you construct a region all things drawn in gaps is __lost, not carried over__. So you will need either two drawtext/string calls with different bounding rectangles or cut a bitmap in two pieces and call drawImage twice.

Comment: Is this meant to be a sort of marquee (running text)? Or is it static? Anyway, you need a rectangle that is larger than the printing area. Calculate the difference between the string length as printed in the *hidden* rectangle and the visible area size. The second string, printed in another *hidden* rectangle, is shown for the remaining part. Labels can be useful here; they have a Paint() event, thus full GDI support. You can both print the strings based on a calculated position or move the rectangles (subject to flickering, needs double buffering).

Answer (score 0):

An example, using two `Labels` and a `TrackBar`.
The `TrackBar` determines a string position inside one Label, which reflects on the second Label each time the string is *moved*.
This cascading effect is generated using the [.Invalidate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invalidate);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) method of the second Label, which is called from the first label [Paint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Paint);k(System.Windows.Forms.Label);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.Label);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) event.

I'm just using [Graphics.MeasureString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Graphics.DrawString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) here.
You could also use the related [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods, but in a Label the measures are the same.

A visual representaton of the result:

[image: Label Marquee]

```
float stringLength = 0F;
string loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
StringFormat MarqueeFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox)
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
    Trimming = StringTrimming.None
};

private void lblMarquee1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(loremIpsum, ((Control)sender).Font, -1, MarqueeFormat);
    PointF stringLocation = new PointF(trackBar1.Value, (((Control)sender).Height - stringSize.Height) / 2);
    stringLength = ((Control)sender).ClientRectangle.Width - stringLocation.X;

    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(loremIpsum, ((Control)sender).Font, Brushes.Black, stringLocation, MarqueeFormat);
    lblMarquee2.Invalidate();
}

private void lblMarquee2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(loremIpsum, ((Control)sender).Font, -1, MarqueeFormat);
    PointF stringLocation = new PointF(-stringLength, (((Control)sender).Height - stringSize.Height) / 2);

    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(loremIpsum, ((Control)sender).Font, Brushes.Black, stringLocation, MarqueeFormat);
}

private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMarquee1.Invalidate();
}
```