# How to make label reappear as soon as it's going out of panel width

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a moving label seem nicer and smoother than just reappearing the whole thing to the left after it has all gone out of panel width .For example label 'Hello' , as soon as 'lo' goes out of bounds in the right I want it to reappear on the left. Is there any possible solution to this ?

Here's the code I have for the label now .

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    label5.Location = new Point(label5.Location.X + 3, label5.Location.Y);
    if (label5.Location.X > this.Width)
    {
        label5.Location = new Point(0 - label5.Width, label5.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution, because a `Label` is a single control. So it cannot appear on the right and left at the same time. You'd need to fake it with a second label, but if this is reasonable depends on the overall application.

Comment: So basically it cannot be done easily, it's not something really important to my program so I wouldn't go into much work to do it. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Its DrawToBitmap() gives you a bitmap object.  You can paint it wherever and as often as you like.

Comment: I think the best solution is usually to anchor or dock controls, instead of positioning them. If you anchor the label to the right edge of its parent, it will move with the window when the window is being resized. Maybe that won't work in your case, but it's worth considering at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using a Label (here, named `lblMarquee` and a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`).

The scrolling time is regulated by both the **`Timer.Interval`** and a float Field (**`marqueeStep`**).
The **`Timer.Tick`** event just calls `lblMarquee.Invalidate()`, causing the Label control to repaint itself.

When the scrolling text, in relation to its current position, goes beyond the limits of the `Label.ClientRectangle`, the section of the text which is not visible anymore is painted at start of the `Label.ClientArea`:

[image: Marquee Label]

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer marqueeTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
string marqueeText = string.Empty;
float marqueePosition = 0f;
float marqueeStep = 4f;

private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    marqueeText = lblMarquee.Text;
    lblMarquee.Text = string.Empty;
    marqueeTimer.Tick += (s, ev) => { this.lblMarquee.Invalidate(); };
    marqueeTimer.Interval = 100;
    marqueeTimer.Start();
}

private void lblMarquee_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var marquee = sender as Label;
    SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(marqueeText, marquee.Font, -1, marqueeFormat);
    PointF stringLocation = new PointF(marqueePosition, (marquee.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2);
    stringLength = marquee.ClientRectangle.Width - stringLocation.X;

    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(marqueeText, marquee.Font, Brushes.Black, stringLocation, marqueeFormat);
    if (marqueePosition >= marquee.ClientRectangle.Width) marqueePosition = 0f;

    if (stringSize.Width + stringLocation.X > marquee.ClientRectangle.Width) {
        PointF partialStringPos = new PointF(-stringLength, (marquee.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(marqueeText, marquee.Font, Brushes.Black, partialStringPos, marqueeFormat);
    }
    marqueePosition += marqueeStep;
}
```

A couple of other implementations you might find useful:

[How to follow the end of a text in a TextBox with no NoWrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990288/7444103)
[How to draw a string on two not adjacent areas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51934307/7444103)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two label controls to do this, but it's not really that difficult. First, create a backup label and set it's properties to look like `label5`:

```
// A backup label for our scrolling label5
private Label label5_backup;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label5.Text = "This is a scrolling label!";

    // Set label5_backup to look like label5
    label5_backup = new Label
    {
        Size = label5.Size,
        Text = label5.Text,
        Top = label5.Top,
        Visible = false
    };

    Controls.Add(label5_backup);

    timer2.Interval = 1;
    timer2.Start();
}
```

Then, in the `Tick` event, as soon as our `label5` starts to leave the client rectangle, set our backup label to the proper distance from the left of the form so that it starts to appear on the other side. And as soon as `label5` is completely off the form, set it's location to match the backup label and then hide the backup label again.

Note that you can just set the `Left` property instead of creating a new `Location` point each time, which simplifies the code a little:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label5.Left++;

    // If label5 starts to go off the right, show our backup on the left side of the form
    if (label5.Right > ClientRectangle.Width)
    {
        label5_backup.Left = label5.Right - ClientRectangle.Width - label5.Width;
        label5_backup.Visible = true;
    }

    // If label5 is all the way off the form now, set it's location to match the backup
    if (label5.Left > ClientRectangle.Width)
    {
        label5.Location = label5_backup.Location;
        label5_backup.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to make the scrolling smoother, only increment the `Left` by `1` each time and reduce the `timer2.Interval` to a third of what it was before (unless it's already at `1`).

Comment: Didn't work for me for some reason , it was still the same as before .